Generators for a Covering Space of $\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$. Are they $\langle a,b^2,bab\rangle$ or $\langle a, b^2, bab^{-1}\rangle$?
I have a short question regarding a covering space of $\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$.
My instructor stated that the generators were $\langle a,b^2,bab\rangle$ instead of $\langle a, b^2, bab^{-1}\rangle$. Is there a mistake here, or are the two answers equivalent because the diagram somehow indicates that $b^2=1$ so that $b=b^{-1}$?

The diagrams in question are provided on page 38 (absolute) of Hatcher.

Note that $b^2=1$ implies $b=b^{-1}$. That shows them to be the same.

@CyclotomicField Why would $b^2 = 1$?

@CyclotomicField Thank you for commenting. I would greatly appreciate if you knew of a pointer as to why $b^2=1$ from the above diagram. I can observe that one of the loops in the covering space happens to correspond to $b^2$, which I would imagine becomes the constraint $b^2=1$ in the base space. I am not sure if my intuition is on the correct track here. Do you have suggestions about how I could make the argument more rigorous. Thanks in advance

@BenSteffan Thank you as well. If $b^2 = 1$ does not hold, what steps should I take to rectify my understanding? Until this point, I had thought that the presence of a 2-cell would imply the existence of a relation in the resultant group. Is that correct in this case? Would $b^2=1$ require me to attach a 2-cell to the above covering space. $\langle a, b^2, bab^{-1}\rangle$ are all the generators of the subgroup of the fundamental group for the base space, right? I know that question sounds obvious, but I'd like to make sure that I don't have a basic mistake in my comprehension. Thanks again

@Talmsmen The fundamental group of a covering space is always a subgroup of the fundamental group of the base space, so no relations either way (although your understanding of attaching 2-cells to impose relations is correct). That's why what CyclotomicField is saying is nonsense. As for the question itself, Hatcher is correct and your instructor is not: $\langle a, b^2, b a b\rangle \subsetneq \langle a, b^2, b a b^{-1} \rangle$ since the former group does not contain any word containing $b^{-1}$ but $b a b^{-1}$ is obviously in the group. I'll write this up into a proper answer :)

...ah, I made a very silly mistake: they're equal after all, since $\langle a, b^2, b a b\rangle$ contains $b^{-2}$ and therefore $b a b^{-1}$, too, after all; sorry for the confusion!

The expressions your instructor and Hatcher give are equivalent.
First of all, since this was a point of confusion, note that $\langle a, b^2, b a b^{\pm 1}\rangle$ are both subgroups of $\langle a, b\rangle$, a free group, so certainly no relations like $b^2 = 1$ hold (alternatively, an application of van Kampen directly tells you that a loop representing $b^2$ is not nullhomotopic).
We then find that $b a b = b a b^{-1} b^2 \in \langle a, b^2, b a b^{-1} \rangle$ and $b a b^{-1} = b a b b^{-2} \in \langle a, b^2, b a b \rangle$ and therefore that both groups are equal.

Thanks for your answer. So you're saying that the multiplicative inverse of $b^2$ is $b^{-2}$, which is present in the group. Then, $bab * b^{-2} = bab^{-1}$ proving that the two subgroups are equivalent to each other. Something about this situation still confuses me. If the two $b$ edges were given the same orientation in the diagram, then the bold vertex would no longer have a local homeomorphism to the wedge sum of two circles. Does that mean that the generators of the group do not necessarily have to "correspond" to the drawing of the diagram?

I'm not quite sure I understand. The edge labels here are chosen precisely so that mapping them down to $S^1 \vee S^1$ gives a covering space. If you mess this up, say by switching the orientation of a single edge, you don't get a covering space (if you get a well-defined map at all), so you lose the relation to the fundamental group of the base (although only up to labels, since you're not actually changing the spaces).

In other words, the labels are chosen precisely so that if you identify them with generators/elements of the fundamental group above, the fundamental group above is directly presented as a subgroup of the fundamental group below. You might want to read the page before this drawing in Hatcher for some more details.

Thanks, that's what I had thought. Most of my confusion stemmed from the fact that we can change the generators for the subgroup of the base space without actually changing the labeling of the edges in the covering space. I guess this sounds obvious now, but at the time, it felt rather delicate.

I read the pages in Hatcher leading up to this diagram, but I wasn't entirely sure about them either, hahah. Maybe I should ask a question about them as well.

@Talmsmen ...and the theory is somewhat subtle! The group theory alone can be a bit of a trap (unless you're used to statements like "the free group on 2 generators has non-finitely generated free subgroups"), and the topological side is also not too easy if you're seeing it for the first time (I remember struggling with this when I first learnt it, too) :)
